# Fill certain rows with mean per group and multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

i have the following dataframe as example:
`df <- data.frame(appid=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3), updateid=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0), eventwindow=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1), use=c(2,2,3,4,4,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,5,4,2,3,4,5), meanuse=c(NA,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,3.5,3.5,3.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,3,3))`

the column meanuse is the column I am trying to create.
It should give the value of mean(use) for the 2 obserations before an event (event window is shown by having event=1). However, when these 2 observations contain data from a different appid it should stop and only take the mean of the 2 observations before an event belonging to the same appid. (in my real dataset I want to do this with 14 observations instead of 2).
The mean of the 2 observstion before the start of the event window should then be pasted in every row where event=1, so not in the same row from where the means are calculated from.

furthermore, one appid will have multiple events so calculating the mean per appid will not work since it has to be the mean of the rows above each event per appid. for this reason I created an identifier for each individual event (updateid).

The eventwindow column always has 3 consecutive 1's. (day before update, day of update, and day after)

I know it are a lot of criteria and I can't get it to work. does anyone have some tips?

Column I want as output is shown below as meanuse.

example: for updateid=2 it takes the mean of row 7 & 8 since these are the 2 rows before the start of the event window (eventwindow is shown by consecutive 1's in event column).
It then pastes this mean in every row within the event window for that event.

````
   appid updateid event use meanuse
1      1        0     0   2      NA
2      1        0     1   2     2.0
3      1        1     1   3     2.0
4      1        0     1   4     2.0
5      1        0     0   4      NA
6      1        0     0   2      NA
7      2        0     0   3      NA
8      2        0     0   4      NA
9      2        0     1   5     3.5
10     2        2     1   4     3.5
11     2        0     1   3     3.5
12     2        0     0   2      NA
13     3        0     0   5      NA
14     3        0     0   4      NA
15     3        0     0   2      NA
16     3        0     1   3     3.0
17     3        3     1   4     3.0
18     3        0     1   5     3.0```
````

Comment: This is hard to understand: "It should give the value of mean(use) for the 2 rows above the first 1 in column event for each event. However, when the columns above contain data from a different appid it should stop and only take the mean of the columns belonging to the same appid." Could you show some example output?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @dash2, the example output is shown in the df at the bottom (column: meanuse). I found it hard to describe, Basically I want to fill the rows that have a 1 in column event, with the mean value of use in the two rows above the first row that has a 1 in the event column. 
I also added some context and explanation of the example for clarity

Comment: OK. I think you're gonna need to work on your question. In particular, I still don't really understant what "the two rows above the first 1 in column event" means, or what "when the columns above contain data from a different appid it should stop..." means (columns can't be above something, they are only to the left or right).

Comment: @dash2 i re-wrote the question. I hope it is clear now!

Comment: Use [`naniar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/getting-started-w-naniar.html)